# How to access a class variable inside a closure in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = ""
  }
  run() {
    b.on("event", function(data) {
      // how to access variable a here?
    })
  }
}
```

how to access a class variable inside a closure?

Comment: You can use `this.a` if you use an arrow function or the other techniques described in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this will preserve the reference to 'this' of `run()` inside the callback

```
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");

const b = new EventEmitter()

class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = "hello i am a"
    }
    run() {
        b.on("event", (data) => {
            console.log(this.a)
        })
    }
}

const classA = new A();

classA.run()

b.emit("event");
```